# Image rendered with GPU shows less noise than CPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, noise-reduction

This is an issue (or feature?) I experience with the blender version 2.76b from the offical ubuntu 16.04 xenial xerus repository. I can't reproduce it with 2.78c or 2.76b build from the blender homepage.

This one is rendered with the xenial release. Almost no noise and fast render time.
[image: xenial gpu]

This one is rendered with CPU and yields the same result as the same version build from the blender homepage. Both four times higher render time and much more noise.
[image]

Is all this maybe due to some specific build options? Because i'd really like to keep the first result even in future blender releases.

It gets even stranger when I decrease the samples from 60 to 10.
Xenial build GPU shows multiple sharp shadows around the object while the Xenial CPU and blender build CPU + GPU gets just noisier.

[image]

[image]

The file from the examples is unchanged between renders, you can try it yourself but the condition occured with every blend file I stumbled upon, therefore it shouldn't be file specific.

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47018

Here another example
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: if you need to post more images, post them to imgur.com and then add the link as part of your question.

Comment: Can you provide the scene for testing?

Comment: And i think title is wrong, in all images i see GPU

Comment: Wait, both of these are rendered with GPU, am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, i messed up my point a bit. The GPU render is different from the CPU render in it's specific blender version, whilst this CPU rendered image is identical to the GPU and CPU rendered images of all other blender versions i tested.

Comment: Stackexchange doesn't allow any more than two links in a post unless i got at least 10 reputation. I don't know how to post the scene or more pictures without violating that. (And I swapped the screenshot with the "right" one)

Comment: See cegaton's comment above for posting more pictures.  Are all settings identical?  I.e. did you just open the exact same .blend file in two different versions with different noise results?

Comment: @skalli when adding links to your text please copy the complete link information. Any extra work that folks have to do to answer is only going to make it harder for those who want to help you...

Comment: What GPU are you using? When you switch from CPU to GPU are you compensating the tile size?

Comment: It makes no difference in the result if i compensate tile size or not but with the same tile size (256x256 for example) the blender.org GPU rendered version takes almost double the time than the Xenial GPU rendered version (with the worse noisy result).

Comment: In the sampling panel, the cpu render uses the [sobol pattern](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/scene/render/integrator.html?#sampling) option. The sobol pattern is not offered with opencl rendering unless the experimental feature set is enabled. That points to the difference could be opencl related, which is known to not be 100% supported.